# Unit Testing - JAVA/XML unable to figure out the error

Tags: java, xml

I am doing a unit testing. The code is as below

```
NodeList nodelist1 = node.getChildNodes();
```

I printed the nodelist1 object by referring one of the stackoverflow link to print a nodelist

it printed the xml as below

```
   <label _FORMAT ="A1">
       <variable name="BOX"/>
       <variable name="CA1"/>
       <variable name="Item"/>  </label>
```

the next operation is inside loop

```
Node node1 = nodelist1.item(j);
```

when I print node1 it prints empty spaces.

can some one help me to understand , why its printing empty spaces ? btw am new to java and XML

Comment: Try [Document.normalizeDocument()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#normalizeDocument--) before iterating through nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print the node

```
getNodeValue()
getNodeName()
getNodeType()
```

If it still doesn't print anything, you have to go further.

You could look at the implementation of `Node`. First consider what the [Javadoc of the Node interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) is saying. The return value of `Node.getNodeValue()` or `Node.toString()` depends on the actual Node type. At the end you have to look up the concrete implementation that is used.

To find out what implementation of `Node` is used, try

```
System.out.println("Node is implemented by " + node1.getClass());`
```

From there you can go further.

Answer (score 0):

There are text nodes between other nodes that can contain only white spaces.

You can check a node type using the following method.

```
org.w3c.dom.Node#getNodeType
```

and compare the result with the constants from the `org.w3c.dom.Node` interface. For example `org.w3c.dom.Node#TEXT_NODE`